# Loop function in jQuery while element is visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to play a short advert-style animation when users scroll down to a particular element in the page. The idea would be to loop this continuously while that particular region of the page is visible, and preferably pause it when it's not.

What I have so far is:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.splash = function() {
    $(".lb").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".button").delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
    $(".t1").animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t2").delay(500).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t3").delay(1000).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t1").delay(2800).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t2").delay(2350).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t3").delay(1900).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t4").delay(3800).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t5").delay(4000).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t4").delay(3000).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t5").delay(2900).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t6").delay(7500).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t7").delay(7700).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t6").delay(3000).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t7").delay(2900).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".t8").delay(11500).animate({left:"-=300"},1000);
    $(".t8").delay(5000).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".arrow").delay(12000).fadeIn(400);
    $(".button").delay(11500).animate({top:"-=30"},700);
    $(".arrow").delay(5000).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    $(".button").delay(4600).animate({left:"-=400"},400);
    setTimeout(splash(), 18000);
   }; 
})( jQuery );


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#splash').is(':visible')) {
    $('#splash').splash();
    }
});
```

This starts playing the function when the #splash div is visible but doesn't loop it. How can I get that working?

(Is this even the best way to lay out all this animation code?)

Thanks

Comment: In that setTimeout you can't just call splash() and expect JS to know what you want to call it on. `$(this).splash();` or `$('#splash').splash();` but not just `splash()`;

Answer (score 1):

```
var Interval='';
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($('#splash').is(':visible')) {
    clearInterval(Interval);
    Interval = setTimeout(function(){
       if($('#splash').is(':visible'))$('#splash').splash();
       else clearInterval(Interval);
    },75);
    }
});
```

set time as you want (in place of 75)

Comment: +1 this makes more sense but there's still a call to splash() left in the function that will error.

Comment: I tried that but it's still not repeating. Do I need to keep the setTimeout in the splash function? If so would it need to be `setTimeout("$(this).splash()",18000);`?